# Am I doing the steps correctly in this epsilon-delta proof?

Tags: proof-verification, epsilon-delta

epsilon finding delta
$$\lim_{x \to -1}(3-4x)=7$$
$$|3-4x-7|<ε$$
$$-ε<3-4x-7<ε$$
$$-ε<-4x-4<ε$$
$$4-ε<-4x<ε+4$$
$$-\fracε4 <-x<\fracε4$$
This point here and down, I feel like I am missing a step to remove the negative from the x? Which I think would flip the logic to $\fracε4>x>-\fracε4$ 
$$|x|<\fracε4=δ$$

delta proving epsilon

$$|x-1|<\fracε4$$
$$-\fracε4<x-1<\fracε4$$
$$1-\fracε4<x<\fracε4+1$$
$$4-ε<-4x<ε+4$$
$$-ε<-4x-4<ε$$
$$-ε<3-4x-7<ε$$
$$|3-4x-7|<ε$$

Comment: When working your way from $-ε<3-4x-7<ε$, remember that you ultimately want some bound on $|x-(-1)|$, since we are taking the limit as $x\to -1$, so you want to try to end up with $x+1$ in the middle, not $x$. Also, you between the last two lines of the first "epsilon finding delta" derivation, you're divideing by $4$, but that should've made it into $1-\fracε4 <-x<\fracε4 + 1$

Comment: Ah, you cleared up a huge question. I wasn't sure on how to interpret the limit going toward a negative. So, then the last part $1-\fracε4<-x<\fracε4+1$ can be interpreted as $|x-(-1)|<\fracε4$ ?

Comment: Yes, it's not very difficult to manipulate $1-\fracε4<-x<\fracε4+1$ into $\fracε4>x-(-1)>-\fracε4$, which is equivalent to $|x-(-1)|<\frac\varepsilon4$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so at looking it again (and with all the helpful tips), and the use of the distributive property..

epsilon to delta

$$\lim_{x \to -1}(3-4x)=7$$
$$|3-4x-7|<ε$$
$$-ε<3-4x-7<ε$$
$$-ε<-4x-4<ε$$
$$-ε<4(-x-1)<ε$$
$$-\fracε4<-x-1<\fracε4$$
$$1-\fracε4 <-x<\fracε4+1$$
$$\fracε4>x-(-1)>\fracε4$$
$$|x-(-1)|<\fracε4$$
$$|x+1|<\fracε4$$

Answer (score 0):

Where you left:

$$-\frac\epsilon4<-x<\frac\epsilon4\implies -\frac\epsilon4<x<\frac\epsilon4\iff|x|<\frac\epsilon4$$

so choose $\;\delta=\frac\epsilon4\;$ and reverse the arrows in your work (first part) ...why can you? If you want around $\;-1\;$ then

$$-\frac\epsilon4<x<\frac\epsilon4\implies1-\frac\epsilon4<x+1<1+\frac\epsilon4$$

so that you can focus on a neighborhood of $\;-1\;$ (fill in gaps)